# Latex: setting another directory for bibliography of natbib package (windows)

Tags: latex, filepath

How to declare a different directory than the working folder with the natbib package using Tex Studio (Windows)? There is a directory for all my bibliographies (*BiblioX.bib*), and I use multiple per document. The bibliography path is : C:\Users\User\Dropbox\PDF\Bib ,and the working folder is : C:\Users\User\Dropbox\R&D\Project\Article\Work_Article .
The following code works:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

    %Bibliography
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{newapa}

    \begin{document}

    \bibliography{../../../../../PDF/Bib/Biblio1,../../../../../PDF/Bib/Biblio2}

    \end{document}
```

The goal would be to be able to use instead:

```
\bibliography{Biblio1,Biblio2}
```

Therefore declare a directory that Natbib would recognize : C:\Users\User\Dropbox\PDF\Bib

I thought about using a variable (or a new command):

```
 \def \BibPath {C:/Users/User/Dropbox/PDF/Bib} 

 \bibliography{\BibPath/Biblio1,\BibPath/Biblio2}
```

But it does not work with the Natbib drop menu allowing to select the reference when writing \cite{ in Tex Studio. Is there a way to change the default of where Natbib/Tex Studio looks for bibliography?
Thanks!